# Mounting hole with vias in OrCAD

Tags: orcad, mounting-holes

I want to create a mounting hole with vias around it. I don't know how to approach it so I've tried to do it on my own. I'm using OrCAD PCB Designer.

I have created a mounting hole padstack with desired diamater, solder mask, antipad and so on. Additionaly, I designed a padstack of via which diameter is 0.4 mm. Now, I want to combine those 2 elements. I mean, I want to place 8 vias around the mounting hole. I deducted that that footprint must be created as a Package symbol. I've added mounting hole as a mechanical element and 8 vias as an electric symbol.

For now, it goes like this.

[image]

I got many DRC errors. How can I fix that problem?

EDIT: In 3D, it looks like this

[image]

It is like it was meant to be.

Preliminary symbol in the library is like that. I want to add a Pack Short parameter to merge the pins into one.

[image]

Comment: What does your symbol look like - show a schematic picture of your symbol please.

Comment: @Andyaka you mean, the symbol in the library in OrCAD capture?

Comment: You might try making your mounting hole a pin like the others. Then make the padstack for the hole just big enough so that its copper doesn't overlap the via copper then, add a copper circle to encompass them all. You'll need to join all the 9 pins up with connections at the schematic level of course.